# Does Sasuke really need a new arm?

Tags: naruto

So we all know that Sasuke does not have an arm. And after his fight, Sakura was saying something about making an arm out of Hashirama's cells. Thing is—Sasuke has the Rinnegan, and knows how to use it. So, he can use the Asura Path technique to get a new arm. So what was the need for an arm made of Hashirama's cells anyway? Why did they make one for Sasuke if he can get a new arm himself? And why is Sasuke missing an arm in the first place? He should have had his own new arm by now.

[image]

Comment: What episode have Sasuke without arm? It would help if you're to include it in your question.

Comment: @AyaseEri Though Its hard pressed to say which ones specifically, Its pretty much all of them that take place after the final Naruto vs Sasuke Fight, when he looses it. Even 12+ years later in the Boruto Movie, he only has one arm.

Comment: @Ryan I uploaded an image from the Boruto Movie in my answer. Arigato.

Comment: Maybe, he just doesn't want an arm. I was wondering the samething, but there might be no difference if he has an arm and if he doesn't.

Comment: Didn't Naruto and Sasuke both lose an arm in the final battle? I heard that from a friend but I haven't seen it yet. So I can't confirm.

Comment: as some of others said Sasuke rejected the arm because he wnted to punish himself and also as a reminder for his past mistakes and his current rule as the protector of the village.

Answer (score 1):

When Naruto and Sasuke battle after they defeat Kaguya, they end up both losing an arm. Tsunade implants a certain cell inside Naruto's missing arm's side to let it grow back. But Sasuke does not want his arm to be recovered because he wants to punish (-ish) himself for all the harm he had caused.

Since, as [EIPsyKongroo said](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/38169/2516), he only received the Magatama Rinnegan when he got the Sage of Six Path chakra, and I don't think it has the ability to recover any lost/damaged cells.

Comment: I could have sworn they talked about growing the arm and then attaching it, like Madara did to the Zetsu which gave him his first Rinnegan eye.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because Sasuke lost a lot of his powers after he sealed Kaguya. (Naruto even lost his Sage of Six Paths more).
Sasuke only had his Rinnegan, so, I don't think he can restore his arm using the Asura path technique.

Comment: Nagato only had the rinnegan as well, but he had all 6 paths. As well, if you argue he lost his power, then he would have lost if after he sealed kaguya, but he then went and did 9 planetary devistations at once, as well as absorbed chakra, both related to 2 of the 6 paths, but after he lost his SOSP power.

Comment: You're right. But that aside, i have never seen sasuke using any powers related to healing.

Comment: I also wanted to add that, Naruto, on the other hand could heal kakashi's eye using his light style, i.e. Asura's power. So maybe healing is a power that only asura incarnates have? Even Hashirama Senju , an Asura incarnate had healing powers

Answer (score 0):

Sasuke is of Uchiha blood line. If he implants Hashirama's cells in his arm, he will activate a Rinnegan in the right eye. He doesn't trust himself yet. So he doesn't attach a new arm like Naruto.

Answer (score 0):

As [Troll dé Mage said](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/39952/2516),

1. Maybe he wants to punish himself for all the harm he had caused OR
2. He thinks that having Hashirama chakra in him would make him too OP and he is afraid that he may turn on the wrong side.

Comment: Please provide additional details or sources to elaborate on and back up your answer.

Answer (score -4):

Sasuke thinks he's cooler with one arm or this is his way of atonement or his trying to be more emo or maybe he thinks he doesnt need it yet

Comment: I don't think so...